# What's the M, V, and C in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I've been looking and looking for a simple answer, yet I always end up with different illustrations and/or explanations. I hope someone can help me to understand.

Are the controllers the C in MVC?
Are models/entities the M in MVC?
Is Thymeleaf/HTML our V in MVC?

Answer (score 1):

- Model - A model contains the data of the application. A data can be a
  single object or a collection of objects.
- Controller - A controller contains the business logic of an
  application. Here, the @Controller annotation is used to mark the
  class as the controller.
- View - A view represents the provided information in a particular
  format. Generally, JSP+JSTL is used to create a view page. Although
  spring also supports other view technologies such as Apache Velocity,
  Thymeleaf and FreeMarker.

https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the link, but honestly those diagrams doesn't make me feel any less confused. Soo services would also be part of the Controller in MVC, as they handle business logic? Just trying to understand how the pattern is implemented in Spring.

Comment: No no, services are additional "layer" in Spring application, same as "DAO", "DTO".
To keep it simple just focus on the controller model and view, do not bring in the service, since that is an additional architecture can can be added ON TOP of MVC.
You can keep your logic in the controller, but it is better to extract it to some specific class, and that leads us to the part of the service layer. But again, MVC is one design pattern, DAO is different, DTO is different, and so on and so on.